# Decimal: Integral number too large in Redshift COPY

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm getting the following error from Redshift.

```
Decimal: Integral number too large
```

This is happening when inserting the following csv line

```
2015-03-20,A_M300X250CONTENT_INT_ADSENSE,3443,3443,1.4,13,,
```

The error is being thrown by `1.4`.

The definition of that column is this:

```
schemaName | tablename | column          | type         | encoding | disktkey | sortkey | notnull 
-----------|-----------|-----------------|--------------|----------|----------|---------|---------
public     | partners  | revenue_partner | numeric(7,7) | none     | false    | 0       | false
```

This copy worked fine when the type was `numeric(7,2)`, but I need to change it to fix a rounding error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numeric(7,7)` means the total number of digits allowed is 7 and all 7 are allocated as decimals. If you want 7 decimals **and** 7 digits you need `numeric(14,7)`

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try this now

Answer (score 2):

Reading the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html

It looks like a `numeric(7,7)` data type can only store values between 0-1 with 7 significant figures. The second number is the number of values you can have after the decimal and the first number - the second number will be the number of values you can have before the decimal.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely the problem! I'm going to accept the above answer just because it also involves a fix